# Gridview highlight specific Item based on SQLITE status in Android

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-gridview

I have a problem in which I want to set highlight `Gridview` item
when the value status from SQLITE is equal to 0. I have the query below
but yet I don't have the idea where to start and how can I highlight the specific item on `GridView`.

The output should something like this, the highlighted item was based on the status on SQLITE which the value is `0`. Is somebody knows how can I implement the highlighted part?. It is very useful for me

[image]

*InventoryListClass*

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new InventoryListAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_inventory_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);


    try {
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,hh_number,card_scanning_status FROM CgList");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            String hhNumber = cursor.getString(1);
            
            int status = cursor.getInt(2);
            if (status==0){
                //IF VALUE IS O IT IS HIGHLIGHTED 
            }
            else {
                // IF VALUE IS 1 NOT HIGHLIGHTED
            }
            list.add(new Inventory(hhNumber, id));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+ e);
    }
```

*InventoryListadapter class*  Updated: I think instead of setting color under InventoryList class I think highlight should be inside of `getView` what I tried is the below code
but it seems it error
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference`

```
  @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Inventory inventory = inventoryList.get(position);
    holder.txtPrice.setText("HH no: "+ inventory.getHHnumber());


    int status = inventory.getStatus();

    if (status==0){
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF108714"));
        //here to set color
    }
    
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `int status = inventory.getStatus();`

So, assuming you've a setter to the status, then you can set it:

```
try {
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT id,hh_number,card_scanning_status FROM CgList");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String hhNumber = cursor.getString(1);
        
        int status = cursor.getInt(2);
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory(hhNumber, id);
        inventory.setStatus(status);
        list.add(inventory);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG, "Error: "+ e);
}
```

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

The `view` parameter of `getView()` is nullable, and therefore you used the `row` instance; but here you called `setBackgroundColor()` on the `view`, not the `row`, so you need to change this to: `row.setBackgroundColor()` instead.

Also make sure to set the default background color in case the status value is not 0, because when the views are recycled you will find some mess among the highlighed and non-highlighted rows.

**Side note:** fore best practice use the 3-arg inflate() method: `inflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false)`

Applying that:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, viewGroup, false);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    
    Inventory inventory = inventoryList.get(position);
    holder.txtPrice.setText("HH no: "+ inventory.getHHnumber());
    int status = inventory.getStatus();

    //here to set color
    if (status==0){
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF108714"));

    } else {
        // set the default color
    }
    
    return row;
}
```